# Classloader variants and usage in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I understand that java.lang.ClassLoader is generally the classloader I extend (when needed). Also, when I see the custom classloaders of tomcat, Jetty etc extend from java.lang.ClassLoader.

I'm curious to understand the purpose and usage of com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.ClassLoader.

Can someone help me understand it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal` is just a repackaging of [Apache BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/). In particular, the class we're interested in (`ClassLoader`) is documented [here](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/util/ClassLoader.html)...

> Drop in replacement for the standard class loader of the JVM. You can use it in conjunction with the [`JavaWrapper`](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/util/JavaWrapper.html) to dynamically modify/create classes as they're requested.
>
> This class loader recognizes special requests in a distinct format, i.e., when the name of the requested class contains with "*$$BCEL$$*" it calls the [`createClass()`](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/util/JavaWrapper.html) method with that name (everything before the *$$BCEL$$* is considered to be the package name. You can subclass the class loader and override that method. "Normal" classes class can be modified by overriding the [`modifyClass()`](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/util/ClassLoader.html#modifyClass(org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass)) method which is called just before [`defineClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

judging by the "bcel" part of the package name that classloader doesnt just load classes, it alters the bytecode on the fly (see the [bcel](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) homepage).

edit: some more info on what they do with it can be found [here](http://www.java.net/node/643837) : "BCEL is used internally by XSLTC to "compile" XSLT stylesheets into bytecodes for execution"